# Using ILNnumerics with c++\cli #ilnumerics

Tags: c++-cli, numerical-methods, ilnumerics

I'm looking for a numerical package that I can call from managed C++\CLI. ILNumerics is aimed at .NET development, so I would assume it can be used with / from C++\CLI.

However I cannot find any reference to this effect.

So can I use ILNumerics with C++\CLI? If so, where do I find typical resources and examples?

If not, is there a numerics package that is compatible with C++\Cli that can be called and integrated as straightforward as with C#? I have a difficult time finding one that is.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: Competent C++/CLI developers generally work from C# samples without difficulty.  That said, I wouldn't even consider using a .NET library for numerical work in C++.  Templates are just so much better, .NET generics can't begin to match the power of template specialization.

Comment: Ben, thanks. I am just starting (moving from Pascal and Fortran), but I noticed the syntax is very similar. I may just try that, to see if it is possible. I noticed there are good and better solutions. As an engineer, I am happy with someting that does the job.